# java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.zhixin.wedeep.homepage.HiltTestApplication> cannot be instantiated

Tags: android, android-testing

I got following error when executed my unit test.

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.zhixin.wedeep.homepage.HiltTestApplication> cannot be instantiated
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1158)
        at com.zhixin.wedeep.homepage.MockTestRunner.newApplication(MockTestRunner.kt:10)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1208)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6533)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:231)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1887)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
```

My HiltTestApplication

```
@CustomTestApplication(BaseApplication::class)
interface HiltTestApplication
```

My BaseApplication

```
open class BaseApplication : Application() {


    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        mInstance = this
        init()
    }

    /**
     * 初始化
     */
    protected fun init() {}

    fun initApiClient() {}

    companion object {
        private var mInstance: Application? = null
        fun getInstance(): Application? {
            return mInstance

        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar exception when trying to run an espresso test, the problem might actually be with the test runner class you have [configured in espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing#instrumented-tests).

---

**Not Working**

```
class CustomTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, name: String?, context: Context?): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, HiltTestApplication::class.java.name, context)
    }
}
```

---

**Working**

```
class CustomTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, name: String?, context: Context?): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, HiltTestApplication_Application::class.java.name, context)
    }
}
```

The Hilt [documentation for custom test applications](https://dagger.dev/hilt/testing.html#custom-test-application) mentions that the `@CustomTestApplication` will generate a `HiltTestApplication` with a `_Application` appended to the interface name.

```
// Generates MyCustom_Application.class
@CustomTestApplication(MyBaseApplication::class)
interface MyCustom
```